# Can someone explain me how to code this program?

Tags: java

I'm currently coding a program in Java, which should check out if the value assign to a variable called "key" is even or odd. Then, if the number is even and divisible by 4 it should print out "even again", otherwise "only even". Also, the program should be able to print out the message "negatively odd" as long as the variable is odd and negative, otherwise it should output "positively odd".

This is what I've done so far:

```
public class Number
{
  public static void main(String[] args){

    int key = 2;

    if (key % 2 == 0) {

      System.out.println("Entered number is even");
    }
    else {

      System.out.println("Entered number is odd ");
    }
  }
}
```

I'm afraid I'm not able to figure out the next part of this exercise. Could someone explain me how to code the missing part?

Comment: Well to check for negative number, use `key < 0`, to check for "even again" use `key % 4 == 0`. That's all you need, just combine the correct conditions.

Comment: Poor title. Rewrite to summarize your specific technical issue.

Comment: Just a point to note, rewording your time to describe the technical problem you're stuck on will help people who are interested in that sort of problem to find your questions - and you'll be more likely to get useful answers.  It'll also make it easier for other people to find your question and benefit from the answers as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, check if the number is positive, negative or a zero.

```
if(key > 0)
{
     // it's positive
}
else if(key < 0)
{
     // it's negative
}
else
{
     // it's zero
}
```

Then check if it is even or odd

```
if(key > 0)
{
     if(key % 2 == 0)
     {
         // it's even
     }
     else
     {
         // it's odd
     }
}
else if(key < 0)
{
     if(key % 2 == 0)
     {
         // it's even
     }
     else
     {
         // it's odd
     }
}
else
{
     // it's zero
}
```

And if the number is even, you can check if it's divisible by 4 and display the appropriate message/s.

The complete program will look like this

```
public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        int key = 10 ;

        if(key > 0) 
        {
            if(key % 2 == 0)
            {
                System.out.println("Positively even");

                if(key % 4 == 0)
                    System.out.println("even again") ;
                else
                    System.out.println("only even");
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Positively odd");
            }
        }
        else if(key < 0)
        {
            if(key % 2 == 0)
            {
                System.out.println("Negatively even") ;

                if(key % 4 == 0)
                    System.out.println("even again") ;
                else
                    System.out.println("only even");
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Negatively odd");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("It's zero");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much user1105! I fully understand the exercise now. So, it seems like, it was about nested if. Cheers.